# Retrieving images from ssms Database using relative path and showing image in picture box in C# visual studio 2012?

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, relative-path

I am making a win-forms program in C# visual studio. I have the relative paths for all the images stored in the database. What I am trying to do is make it so that when an item is selected from the combobox, a stored proc is executed it returns the datatable and places everything in the relevant textbox.

However, one column is the relative path for the .JPEG image. I need to get the relative path and somehow convert it so that the program gets the actual image and display it in the PictureBox.

```
private void cmbEOselect_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable SO = new DataTable();

    txtbEOname.Text = (String)SO.Rows[cmbEOselect.SelectedIndex]["Name"];

    String folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) 
    + @"\........\.jpeg      pBoxOils.Load(folder);
    txtbEObottn = (String)SO.Rows[cmbEOselect.SelectedIndex]["BottanicalName"];
    txtbEOext.Text = (String)SO.Rows[cmbEOselect.SelectedIndex]["Extraction"];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txtbEOname.Text = (String)PEO.Rows[cmbEOselect.SelectedIndex]["Name"];
            String folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) +   @"" + PEO.Rows[cmbEOselect.SelectedIndex]["IMAGE"];
            pBoxOils.Load(folder);
```